Unmet dependencies prevent programs being installed or updated; removing the culprit package does not work
Out of curiosity (I don't remember why exactly, some program used in a guide I was reading wasn't installed, and I followed the CL instructions on what packages to download) I tried to install linux-tools to my laptop running on Ubuntu 23.10.1. The package wasn't installed properly because of some unmet dependencies, and can't be removed either:
$ sudo apt purge linux-tools-6.5.0-26
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-6.5.0-26-generic : Depends: linux-tools-6.5.0-26 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

sudo apt --fix-broken install returns a similar error:
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hwdata libbotan-2-19 libminizip1 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5x11extras5 libtspi1 libzxcvbn0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/450 kB of archives.
After this operation, 548 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 405820 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_6.5.0-9.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (6.5.0-9.9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_6.5.0-9.9_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/cpupower', which is also in package linux-laptop-tools-common 6.5.0-1006.9
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_6.5.0-9.9_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I can't run sudo apt upgrade because of the same error (Unmet dependencies). sudo dpkg --configure -a doesn't work either, as well as sudo apt remove and sudo apt autoremove. I also tried (using an Ask Ubuntu answer I can't find anymore) the following:
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list ~/
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
software-properties-gtk

and then checking the boxes allowing downloading updates. This didn't work, either. When trying to install a package (an e-reader, in this case, I also encounter dependency problems):

sudo apt install okular
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-6.5.0-26 : Depends: linux-tools-common but it is not going to be installed
 okular : Depends: kinit but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: kio but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5activities5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5archive5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5bookmarks5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5codecs5 (>= 4.96.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5completion5 (>= 5.81.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5configcore5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5configgui5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5configwidgets5 (>= 5.81.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5coreaddons5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5crash5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5i18n5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5itemviews5 (>= 4.96.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5jobwidgets5 (>= 4.96.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5kexiv2-15.0.0 (>= 23.08.1~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5kiocore5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5kiogui5 (>= 5.69.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5kiowidgets5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5parts5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5pty5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5purpose-bin but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5purpose5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5textwidgets5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5wallet-bin but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5wallet5 (>= 5.68.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5widgetsaddons5 (>= 5.77.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5windowsystem5 (>= 5.89.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5xmlgui5 (>= 5.79.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libokular5core11 (= 4:23.08.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libphonon4qt5-4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqmobipocket2 (>= 4:23.08.1~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt5texttospeech5 (>= 5.12.0~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: phonon4qt5 but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: okular-extra-backends but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: qtspeech5-flite-plugin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Also, regarding similar problem description here, I definitely have enough RAM (16 GB afaik).
sudo apt clean and sudo apt autoclean (recommended here) don't solve the problem. Restricted and universe sources are allowed. sudo apt install -f does not help. sudo apt -u dist-upgrade raises the same error.
UPD:
An advice from here has helped me at least partially:
sudo apt --fix-broken install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"

appears to fix the problem for the moment, but I am not sure if it won't cause any problems in the future.

Does this answer your question? dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."

Em, not sure. I resorted to --force-override, but I see that this method is not recommended, and without --force-override dpkg wasn't able to delete the package
